# dyld: Symbol not found: _SecTrustEvaluateWithError

Tags: deno, freshjs

I'm on MacPro OS 10.12 (can not be upgraded to 10.13 or beyond bc HW is old!) and I get below error.
Any help please
Thanks

Task start deno run -A --watch=static/,routes/ dev.ts
Watcher Process started.
The manifest has been generated for 3 routes and 1 islands.
Server listening on http://localhost:3000
dyld: Symbol not found: _SecTrustEvaluateWithError
Referenced from: /Users/kemalgencay/Library/Caches/esbuild/bin/esbuild-darwin-
64@0.14.39
Expected in: flat namespace

```
An error occured during route handling or page rendering. Error: The service was 
stopped
at https://deno.land/x/esbuild@v0.14.39/mod.js:1304:25
at https://deno.land/x/esbuild@v0.14.39/mod.js:633:9
at afterClose (https://deno.land/x/esbuild@v0.14.39/mod.js:611:7)
at https://deno.land/x/esbuild@v0.14.39/mod.js:1844:11
error: Uncaught (in promise) BrokenPipe: Broken pipe (os error 32)
Watcher Process finished. Restarting on file change...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"devDependencies": {
  "esbuild-wasm":"latest"
},
"overrides": {
  "esbuild":"npm:esbuild-wasm@latest"
}
```

Just add this to the package.json
And then run: `npm install`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: After this change, I am getting this error: `Invalid comparator: npm:esbuild-wasm@latest`.